# Smallest possible package for distributing MinGW with another program

Tags: c++, deployment, mingw

I'm working on an open source programming language, and I want my users to be able to distribute standalone .exe files from their programs. My strategy is to have 3 components:

1. A DLL that contains the interpreter
2. A small .o object file (generated once from C) that invokes the DLL to start the execution
3. A generated .o file that contains a binary representation of the user's program, to be embedded as a binary blob with #2.

When the user requests an .exe, #2 and #3 are linked together, and the resulting executable can be distributed with #1. So far so good.

The problem I have now is that this means MinGW has to be bundled with the language, in order to do the linking step. I don't want to have my users manually download MinGW (my primary audience are children) and the standard MinGW distribution is more than a 100 megabytes, so bundling all of that would spoil the minimalism of my language's download (it's currently ~5 mb).

My question is: Is there a definitive list of files to be yanked from \MinGW and bundled with the language by themselves, that would make g++.exe work to link two .o files and the needed libraries together?

Alternative solutions are also welcome (for example a freely redistributable C++ compiler that's more easily bundled with other apps).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and rip g++ out of MinGW. It will generate your list of dependencies. Alternatively, you could use [cygwin](http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html), which reduces your footprint to around 15 megs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I'm not sure dependency walker will take me far since the GNU toolchain probably has many dependencies between processes and not just between process & DLL, the Unix way and all that. Also, I'll check the cygwin tip :)